# PM2 with Node.js -- "unsave" a process list?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Following this doc: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#saving-current-process-list

`pm2 save` will save the current process list to `$PM2_HOME/.pm2/dump.pm2`

That all works perfectly, but how do I "un-save"?

Obviously can just delete the `dump.pm2` but I have no idea of the repercussions or potential artifacts left from doing that.

Comment: Maybe `rm $PM2_HOME/.pm2/dump.pm2`? Don't think is possible through PM2

Comment: Yea I mentioned that in the question -- I'm going to try it in non-prod first but I have no idea if that will leave any artifacts around/etc. I was also thinking of just clearing the process list and doing another `save` to overwrite the current one.

Answer (score 5):

Process lists are saved in the file: `$PM2_HOME/dump.pm2`

To *unsave* all processes, run the command:

```
pm2 cleardump
```

This replaces `dump.pm2` with a fresh file.
**Warning:** this cannot be undone.

Comment: Thanks - Is this documented anywhere other than the in-app help? I checked the pm2 website, they don't mention the word `cleardump` anywhere on the reference page and I searched for the term too and found nothing. I no longer work with NodeJS so I don't have pm2 installed anywhere to verify this right now, was hoping to check the docs.